# "does not live long enough" when creating a binary tree of references that can be passed between threads

Tags: scope, rust, lifetime

I am trying to write a binary tree that can be passed around between threads without having to be copied every time.  I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this with Rust's restrictions around lifetimes.

```
use std::thread::spawn;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<'a> {
    left: &'a i32,
    right: &'a i32,
}

fn main() {
    let l = 3;
    let r = 4;
    let n = Node {
        left: &l,
        right: &r,
    };

    spawn(|| {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    });
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `l` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
13 |           left: &l,
   |                 ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
17 | /     spawn(|| {
18 | |         println!("{:?}", n);
19 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `l` is borrowed for `'static`
20 |   }
   |   - `l` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `r` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:16
   |
14 |           right: &r,
   |                  ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
17 | /     spawn(|| {
18 | |         println!("{:?}", n);
19 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `r` is borrowed for `'static`
20 |   }
   |   - `r` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `n`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:17:11
   |
17 |     spawn(|| {
   |           ^^ may outlive borrowed value `n`
18 |         println!("{:?}", n);
   |                          - `n` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 | /     spawn(|| {
18 | |         println!("{:?}", n);
19 | |     });
   | |______^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `n` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
17 |     spawn(move || {
   |           ^^^^^^^
```

I understand why it would think they don't live long enough, but how should I restructure this so that they do?

Answer (score 3):

In your situation, you create a `Node` object with references to variables you defined in your `main()` function, and pass it to a new thread. The problem is that you have absolutely no guarantee that this thread will finish before the thread of your `main()`, and you risk your original variables going out of scope before the references, hence the error.

Given that you wish to build a tree, I think the easiest fix would be to have your `Node` type own its fields, like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    left: i32,
    right: i32,
}
```

you will then have no more lifetime issues.

To share it between several threads without copying it, you can use the [`std::sync::Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) wrapper; it's for exactly this purpose. You can do something like:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let n = Arc::new(Node { left: 3, right: 4 });

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let n_thread = n.clone();
        spawn(move || {
            println!("{:?}", n_thread);
        });
    }
}
```

If you need to give your other threads write access to the `Node` as well, you probably will want to wrap it in a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or a [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html), keeping whole thing inside an `Arc`.